# Returning next match to a equal value in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I often need to search through columns to find the match to values and then return the according value. 
My issue is that `INDEX`and `MATCH`always return the first value in the column.

EX. I got 7 car dealers and this is the sales last month. Oslo and Berlin sold the same ammount and `INDEX(D:E,MATCH(B1,E:E,0),1))` in column `C` will return the first hit from column D.

```
A       B      C                   D         E
rank  Sales  Delaer
1     409    London         |     Tokyo     272
2     272    Tokyo          |     London    409
3     257    Hawaii         |     oslo      248
4     255    Stockholm      |     numbai    240
5     248    Oslo           |     Berlin    248
6     248    Oslo           |     hawaii    257 
7     240    Numbai         |     Stockholm 255
```

At the moment my best solution is to first find the row each value in `B` got in `E` with `MATCH(B1,E:E,0)` and add that to a new column (`column F`). Then I can add another formula in the next column, which is what I currently have to do:
`=IF(F2=F1;MATCH(F2;INDIRECT("F"&(1+F1)):$F$7;0))+F2`

Is there a better approach at this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In B2 use the following standard formula,

```
=IFERROR(LARGE(E$2:E$8, ROW(1:1)), "")
```

Fill down as necessary.

In C2 use the following standard formula,

```
=INDEX(D$2:D$8, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$7)/(E$2:E$8=B2), COUNTIF(B$2:B2, B2)))
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image: Oslo_twice]

[Optional] - Repair the ranking in column A.

In A2 use the following formula,

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B$2:B$8>=B2)/(COUNTIFS(B$2:B$8, B$2:B$8&"")))
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image: repair_oslo]

Comment: Please note a small modification to the primary INDEX/AGGREGATE formula where the COUNTIF looks at column B, not column E.