# Find when two different values match in a table

Tags: excel

I have a table with location in one column and a code in other. I want to choose a location and code and when both are on the same row, pull out this data.
How would i go about this?
The location and code correspond to a value which will then be plotted on a bar graph as i want to compare all the different combinations of location and code.
I have about 1000 values so some are repeated together many times.

Comment: Can you elaborate more with some example?

Comment: You might be able to use an auto filter, or the advanced filter, depending on the details of your request

Comment: See [Excel: match two columns and output third … AND… there are multiple instances in each column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31979340/excel-match-two-columns-and-output-third-and-there-are-multiple-instance/31980952#31980952).

Answer (score 0):

If there is many repeated [this might](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060072/returning-next-match-to-a-equal-value-in-a-column) help you with that.

When that's solved I think `INDEX` and `MATCH`would be sufficient