# Top 5 formula with a tiebreaker using LARGE

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have spreadsheet that have a list of items in column A and according values in column B, something like:

```
A        B
item1    2
item2    3
item3    3
item4    5
item5    6
```

Now in column C I created a formula that would return the names connected to the top 5 values that looks like:

```
=INDEX(A:B;MATCH(LARGE(B:B;1);B:B;0);1)
=INDEX(A:B;MATCH(LARGE(B:B;2);B:B;0);1)
=INDEX(A:B;MATCH(LARGE(B:B;3);B:B;0);1)
=INDEX(A:B;MATCH(LARGE(B:B;4);B:B;0);1)
=INDEX(A:B;MATCH(LARGE(B:B;5);B:B;0);1)
```

Unfotunately this formula is not tie-sensitive. So if there are more than one item with the same value it would return the name of only one of them. So in my example `=INDEX(A:B;MATCH(LARGE(B:B;3);B:B;0);1)` and `=INDEX(A:B;MATCH(LARGE(B:B;4);B:B;0);1)` would return the same value: `item2`. I would need to modify this function so it would return different values. It doesn't matter for me if `item2` would be before or after `item3`, I just want them both to be displayed. Could anyone help me with this one?

Comment: you can check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060072/returning-next-match-to-a-equal-value-in-a-column

Answer (score 0):

If you like using `LARGE()`, then just de-duplicate the scores.

With data in columns **A** and **B**, in **C1** enter:

```
=B1
```

and in **C2** enter:

```
=B2+(COUNTIF($B$1:B1,B2))/100
```

and copy **C2** downwards:

[image]

Now `LARGE()` can be used on column **C** as column **C** will have only unique values !